# package to encapsulate float64 in protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I was working in a microservice to create subscriptions in Stripe. One of the fields is listed as a `float64` where I set it up as a `float` in the `.proto` file. This cast the field as a `float32` not `float64`.

I cannot see a direct way to make `protobuf` to produce a file with the field typed as `float64`. Can someone help me here? Is there any special package for `protobuf` that encapsulates a `float64`?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in [Scalar Value Types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar), `float64` in Go is defined with `double` in protobuf. So instead of writing:

```proto
float a_field = 1;
```

you will write:

```proto
double a_field = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see that one. I guess I was too tired.